# C++ runtime error in Linux ::glibc detected free(): invalid next size (fast): Stack with void ptr element

Tags: c++, dynamic, error-handling, stack, glibc

This is my first question so i would apologize if this is too silly. I have tried to search and still unable to find the problem with the code. I am debugging someone else's code which is giving this error in linux and it ran just fine in Solaris.

```
*** glibc detected ***  free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x096c72b0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6[0xa986c5]
/lib/libc.so.6(cfree+0x59)[0xa98b09]
...
```

The code is huge with lot of internal logic but i have tried to create a sample of where the problem might be..

```
Typedef Struct _FIELD
{
Int  size;
Char str[25];
Void *pData;
Void *pValue;
}FIELD;

Class ABC
{
 FIELD * field1;
 FIELD* getFIeld(int);
 …}

ABC::ABC()
{
field1=NULL;
}
ABC::~ABC()
{ 
for (int I = 0; I < total_num; i++)
{
    free (field1[i].pData);
   free(field1[i],pValue);
 }
free(field1);
}

FIELD* ABC::getField(int total_num)
{
FIELD *pFields = NULL;
pFields = GetValues( total_num);//just sets up pFields

field1 = malloc ( total_num * sizeof(FIELD));
for (int i =0 ; i<total_num; i++)
 {
 // earlier this code was memcpy, memcpy(&field1, &pFields, sizeof(FIELD)) I have       changed this to explicit copy
 Strcpy(field1[i].str, pFields[i].str);
  field1[i].size = pFields[i].size;
  field1[i].pData = malloc(fields[i].size);
  field1[i].pValue = malloc(fields[i].size);
   //I am not doing strdup for pData and PValue as I checked they are null at this point.
 }
 free(pFields);
 return(field1);

}
…
//Main 
FIELD* field1 = NULL;

  ……
 field1 = getField(n);
  …….

 field1 =getField(n)
 …
```

Again I would like to apologize if this is some thing obvious..

I am sure this is due the way memory is allocated to the struct.

THanks!

Comment: Obligatory unhelpful advice: stop using raw pointers so much. `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr`, `array` and `vector` will make your life vastly easier.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a buffer overflow somewhere.  The error message that you're getting from glibc indicates that the heap has been corrupted, usually by overwriting the internal records that track used and free blocks.  glibc is very aggressive about trying to detect these sorts of errors, more so than other platforms; you probably have the same bug elsewhere, but the libc isn't detecting it.

As for exactly where the bug is, I don't see it directly in your code, but that code is making quite a few assumptions (such as pre-allocating buffers of the size recorded in the data structure) and the rest of the program may not be following those assumptions.

Short version: I would install valgrind and run your program under it.  This is a run-time memory debugger for UNIX that will tell you when you've written past the end of allocated memory and what line of code has that problem.  It's the first thing to reach for in this sort of problem.

Comment: I have installed Valgrind and run the binary under it and it gave me the invalid free() pretty much the same message i got while running the binary under gdb. What would be the best way to use valgrind for identifying the exact point when it gets corrupted.

just running it as /../val/bin/valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes <binary_name> <args>

or is there some other way ?

Thanks!

Comment: If `valgrind` reports an invalid free, it should have given you more information about where the memory was allocated from and where else it was freed.  (Be sure that you built the binary with debugging symbols, of course, but if you're already using `gdb`, that shouldn't have been an issue.)  It looks like you're running valgrind properly -- there wasn't any other output about memory issues prior to that free?